# How to get called when glassfish finished starting web services in current EAR deployment

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-8, glassfish-5

I need a way to get called when the start of the current EAR services are done. Specifically web services.
The `@PostConstruct` annotation is usefull, but too early.
A commented pseudo `server.log` should show the problem:

```java
// All JNDI bindings get established
[2020-05-19... Portable JNDI names for EJB TemplateCreator: [java:global/AllInOne/L...]

// @PostConstruct methods get called. Far too early.
[2020-05-19... Trying to interact with web services failed]

// Starting of web services
[2020-05-19... Mojarra 2.3.14... for context '/app' gets initialized]

[2020-05-19... Loading application [AllInOne#TheApp.war] at [/app]]]

// Other web services get started the same...

// ========== This! Exactly here I need the call! Not earlier! =================
```

What would be the alternative to `@PostConstruct` which gets called at the right moment?

Comment: Don't know which type of web services you have, but you could try to use a @WebListener. See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384068/4962355

Comment: While that sounds promising... Would that work if the @WebListener class is outside of the deployed WAR?

Comment: TBH I don't know. If you want a specific WAR to be started lastly maybe you can assign it a different deployment order via `--deploymentorder`

Comment: Actually I solved it already this way. I created an extra WAR around my target class, so I could deploy it last, and then the methods I need are called at the right time. But: It's actually a bit messy to have a complete WebService, just as a container so the method gets called at the right time.